# ms-access automatic adding attachments

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

ok so i am stuck here...

I have tblParts with fields "Print" and Attachment.
Print field is populated with hyperlinks to a .pdf print.

I am trying to create a macro to use the path to create an attachment.

this is what I have come up with so far...

Data types below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2Skd.png)
everything works fine up until:

```
   Set Attach = rs("Field1")
   If Not IsNull(Attach.Value) Then
      Attach.LoadFromFile attachmentPath      'this line is giving an error Invalid field data type.
   Else
      Attach.Value = base64Data
   End If
```

the rest of the code is below...
thank you for any help.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Sub UpdateAttachments()
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim attachmentPath As String
Dim attachmentData() As Byte
Dim hyperlinkPath As String
Dim filePath As String
Dim Attach As DAO.Field2

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblParts")

'Loop through each record in the table
Do Until rs.EOF
    'Get the hyperlink path from the "Print" column
    hyperlinkPath = rs("Print")
   
    'Extract the file path from the hyperlink
    filePath = hyperlinkPath
    filePath = Mid(filePath, 10)
    filePath = Replace(filePath, "%20", " ")
    filePath = Replace(filePath, "#", "")
    attachmentPath = filePath
   
   'Read the binary data from the file
   Open attachmentPath For Binary As #1
   ReDim attachmentData(LOF(1))
   Get #1, , attachmentData
   Close #1
   
   'Encode the binary data in Base64 format
   Dim base64Data As String
   base64Data = EncodeBase64(attachmentData)
   
    'Update the "Field1" attachment with the Base64-encoded data
    rs.Edit
    Set Attach = rs("Field1")
    If Not IsNull(Attach.Value) Then
        Attach.LoadFromFile attachmentPath
    Else
        Attach.Value = base64Data
    End If
    rs.Update
   
    'Move to the next record
    rs.MoveNext
Loop

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
End Sub

Private Function EncodeBase64(data() As Byte) As String
    Dim objXML As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Dim objNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement
   
    Set objXML = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Set objNode = objXML.createElement("b64")
   
    objNode.DataType = "bin.base64"
    objNode.nodeTypedValue = data
   
    EncodeBase64 = objNode.Text
   
    Set objNode = Nothing
    Set objXML = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Your description doesn't match your code
You say 
> I have tblParts with fields "Path" and Attachment. Path field is
> populated with hyperlinks to a .pdf print.

Yet your code recordset only references `rs("Field1")` and `rs("Print")`

What have you defined as your field data types?

Comment: correction, rs("Print") is the correct field name. data types are HyperLink for Print and Attachment for attachement.

Comment: What is content of attachmentPath variable? How is 'rest of code' related to issue?